# MySQL drop procedure

Tags: mysql

I'm running into a headwind performing a simple update statement against a db in MySQL. It returns error code: 1305. PROCEDURE dwsystem.sp_DWLogging does not exist

This is the statement I'm using{works like a champ in mssql}

```
UPDATE `dwserver`
SET
`machine_name` = 'Desktop'
```

I've tried using the `drop procedure If exists` statement and it too returns
1305

```
Drop Procedure IF EXISTS dwsystem.sp_DWLogging; error 1305
Drop Procedure IF EXISTS DWLogging; error 1305
```

I'm sure this is a simple matter, but, for the life of me, I can't find the correct syntax to allow me to update the table values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the `UPDATE` statement have to do with the procedure?

Comment: 1305 is a warning and can be ignored

Comment: The update statement is what is actually triggering the 1305 procedure error. I understand that the 1305 error is a warning, but, it prevents the update from taking effect.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on dwserver table that calls this stored proc? If you do, then you either need to completely drop the trigger, or modify not to include this stored proc or you actually need to create the stored proc in question.

Comment: This is about as simple a mysql install as you can get. No triggers or procedures. I simply need to update 3 rows and 2 hrs later, still scratching my head.

Comment: An update statement is not going to call an arbitrary, non-existing stored procedure on its own. Something must trigger that call to the stored proc. I found the following link on the Internet when I searched for your stored procedure name and it refers to dwsystem.sp_DWLogging stored procedure, so I do think you have a trigger somewhere: https://nanopdf.com/download/backup-in-fremdsystem-importieren-aus-supportfall_pdf

Comment: I think you should talk to your docuware support on directly using their database. This is not something you can really expect to get support on SO, since docuware is a prorietary product and its database structure is not documented publicly.

Comment: I thought I'd follow your advice and create the stored procedure that it is referencing just to get past the error. Still throwing a 1305.As this is a test environment, it isn't worth the hassle of creating a support ticket. Thanks anyway.